# Selecting set of vertices (not complete feature) and pasting into another feature in same or different layer using QGIS?

Tags: vertices, copy, qgis-3

I want to select a few vertices in QGIS 3.2.2 (for example a bend in a river) and copy that into another feature in the same or in a different layer.  The pasted vertices would be added to existing vertices in a feature.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Oops. QGIS 3.2.2

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide any requested clarifications.